# Customisation of UINavBar height (different views require nav bars with different heights)

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I need to implement UINavigationBar with 2 different heights.
Ex: I have two kinds of navigation bar 1. normal height 2. customised height (increased height of nav bar). I am working in Swift 2.3 my app supports ios8.0 >

My workaround : I have subclassed UINavigationBar with custom height and assigned that class to NavigationBar in navigation controller. Now I see all my views height got changed to custom height. But for few views I want normal height (44) of the navigation bar to be sustained. 
I tried setting navigation bar frame back to 44 (in views where normal height is required). Here I face a problem whenever my app is getting is going to background state and getting active NavigationBar is setting back to custom height. 
I want a solution for handling UINavigationBar with different heights with one UINavigationController.

Attaching Screenshots:[image: Base View]

View 1 :
[image: View 1]

View 2:
[image: View 2]

View 2: (after app getting active)
[image: View 2 - screen shot 2]

From the above screen shots, I Base view is landing view when app is launched, here NavigationBar is customised. 
 1. View 1 is pushed from BaseView here NavigationBar is customised bar (I want custom bar in this view, no issues in this view)
 2. View 2 is pushed from BaseView here NavigationBar is customised bar but still I want default height (44) of the bar in this view so in viewWillAppear I am setting the navigationbar frame to 44. and it is getting set properly
 But whenever the app is getting active from background it is resetting back to custom height (You can see in the last screen shot)

I want a solution where I can have custom bar with increased height and default height and use them appropriately as per the views.

Comment: Please uploads some screen short of this problem so we better understand...

Comment: @MohitDodiya Thanks for immediate reply, I have attached few screenshots can you please check them.

Comment: which divice you run this app???

Comment: @MohitDodiya I have taken these screenshot from simulator, but I see same behaviour when I run the app on physical device (iPhone 6S)

Comment: @Gupta Hi, You should not create subclass of `navbar`. See [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/NavBar/Introduction/Intro.html). It's common approach from `apple` for customizing `navbar`.

Answer (score -1):

First you set custome NavigationBar after select that view and set its Autoresize like this..[image]

and in viewWillAppeare method hide nabvigation bar .

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
 {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
 }
```

Comment: can you please explain in detail how to set auto resize to UINavigationBar. I couldn't set the way you suggested.

Comment: Sorry gupta because of late reply..
First you select your custom view after goes in "Show the size inspector" left drawer in xcode . set autoresize like i upload first image.